# any bits unsigned integer

Tags: c++, classes

This is a class that acts as an unsigned integer with a variable amount of bits.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

// any amount of bits inteter
// note: stores with size of uint64_t
template <uint8_t bits_g>
class uintx_t {
private:
    uint64_t Val;
    uint8_t bits;

    constexpr inline uint64_t _formatBits(
        const uint64_t& val,
        const uint16_t& _bits
    ) {return val & UINT64_MAX >> (64-_bits);}

public:
    uintx_t(const int64_t& val) {
        bits = bits_g;
        if      (bits > 64) bits = 64;
        else if (bits < 1 ) bits = 1;
        Val = _formatBits(val, bits);
    }
    
    void operator= (uintx_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(val.Val, bits);
    }
    void operator= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(val, bits);
    }

    bool operator== (const int64_t& val) {
        return (Val == val);
    }
    bool operator!= (const int64_t& val) {
        return (Val != val);
    }
    bool operator> (const int64_t& val) {
        return (Val > val);
    }
    bool operator< (const int64_t& val) {
        return (Val < val);
    }
    bool operator>= (const int64_t& val) {
        return (Val >= val);
    }
    bool operator<= (const int64_t& val) {
        return (Val <= val);
    }

    int64_t operator+ (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val + val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator- (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val - val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator* (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val * val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator/ (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val / val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator% (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val % val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator| (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val | val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator& (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val & val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator^ (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val ^ val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator<< (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val << val, bits));
    }
    int64_t operator>> (const int64_t& val) {
        return (_formatBits(Val >> val, bits));
    }

    uintx_t& operator++ () {
        Val = _formatBits(++Val, bits);
        return *this;
    }
    uintx_t& operator-- () {
        Val = _formatBits(--Val, bits);
        return *this;
    }
    uintx_t operator++ (int) {
        Val = _formatBits(++Val, bits);
        return *this;
    }
    uintx_t operator-- (int) {
        Val = _formatBits(--Val, bits);
        return *this;
    }

    void operator+= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val+val, bits);
    }
    void operator-= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val-val, bits);
    }
    void operator*= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val*val, bits);
    }
    void operator/= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val/val, bits);
    }
    void operator%= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val%val, bits);
    }
    void operator|= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val|val, bits);
    }
    void operator&= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val&val, bits);
    }
    void operator^= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val^val, bits);
    }
    void operator<<= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val<<val, bits);
    }
    void operator>>= (const int64_t& val) {
        Val = _formatBits(Val>>val, bits);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream& os,
        uintx_t& UX
    ) {
        os << std::to_string(UX.Val);
        return os;
    }

    template <typename T>
    explicit operator T() const {
        return (T)Val;
    }
};
```

The issue I have with this right now is that overloading an operator with another `uintx_t` doesn't work without having it casted to another type. I tried to overload the operators specifically for `uintx_t` but since 2 objects could have differing amount of bits, I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code Style

Your coding style changes throughout your code, you should try to stick to one. Also, you should never name things starting with an `_`, this is reserved for the standard library and compilers.

Some rules I like (based on the standard library) are for example:

- name your templates in PascalCase,
- name your members in snake_case.

### Bits between 1 and 64

I feel like it is misleading to allow the user to use bit values less than 1 or bigger than 64, and silently put it in that range. I would recommend doing the following instead:

```cpp
template <std::uint8_t bits>
requires(bits >= 1 && bits <= 64)
struct uintx_t {
```

This way, if the user tries to have a number of bits higher than 64 or less than 1, the code will not compile.

### `bits` member

Why do you have a member `uint8_t bits`? If the only reason is the one above, then you can remove it. If you absolutely want to keep it you should mark it `static constexpr`, this will avoid having a copy on all your objects. Also, thanks to memory alignment, having the `uint8_t` makes the struct 128 bits on my computer, so it doubles the size of the struct.

### `const uint64_t& val`

You should not pass integers by `const &`, they are small enough that a copy does not matter (I mean that it is the same to copy a 64 bits pointer and a 64 bits integer), it removes an indirection, and it makes the code cleaner.

### Format bits

For someone just reading the code, it is unclear what the priorities are in the format bit function, so I would recommend adding parenthesis.

You can also add the `static` qualifier. I would argue you can even move the function out of the class, this would make it more testable.

With all the above comments taken into account as well, this gives:

```
constexpr static inline uint64_t formatBits(uint64_t val, uint16_t bits) {
    return val & (UINT64_MAX >> (64 - bits));
}
```

### Operators

Not really feedback here, but more a question. Why do the operators return an `int64_t` and not a `uintx_t` ?

Regarding your issue with overloading your operators for `uintx_t`, you can just template your operators: `template <uint8_t OtherBits>`. Should you require more assistance, I would recommend heading over to StackOverflow.

Comment: We generally don't answer questions where the code isn't working as intended.